# Count frequency of values in a column in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera

I have something like this:

```
ColA ColB
a    xxx
b    yyy
c    xxx
d    yyy
e    xxx
```

I need to find out the number of times each value of `ColB` occurs.

Output:

```
xxx 3
yyy 2
```

Here's what I've been trying:

Considering `A` has my data,

```
grunt> B = GROUP A by ColB;
grunt> DESCRIBE B;
B: {group: chararray,A: {(ColA: chararray,ColB: chararray)}}
```

Now I'm confused, do I do something like this?

```
grunt> C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT(B.ColB)
```

So I need the output to be like this,

```
xxx 3
yyy 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE GROUP AS ColB, COUNT(A) as count;
```

Comment: Hi, For me it is showing- Invalid field projection. Projected field [GROUP] does not exist in schema: group:bytearray,A:bag{:tuple(ColA:bytearray,ColB:bytearray)}.

Comment: I am getting the same as yours @UnmeshaSreeVeni. The link is broken... What you've done?

Answer (score 0):

Use lower-case for 'group as', it works for me:

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as ColB, COUNT(A) as count;
```

Comment: That's because keywords are not case sensitive... along with this question being seven years old...

Comment: But it's not gonna work if you used GROUP AS. Someone might find it useful tho.